# Why is the Walrus Operator not working when implemented inside the return statement of this function?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, math, walrus-operator

I was trying to solve this problem when I thought of implementing the operator inside the return statement. Here is the question:

*Digital root is the recursive sum of all the digits in a number.
Given n, take the sum of the digits of n. If that value has more than one digit, continue reducing in this way until a single-digit number is produced. The input will be a non-negative integer.*
Examples:

1. 16  -->  1 + 6 = 7
2. 493193  -->  4 + 9 + 3 + 1 + 9 + 3 = 29  -->  2 + 9 = 11  -->  1 + 1 = 2
3. 942  -->  9 + 4 + 2 = 15  -->  1 + 5 = 6

Code:

```
def digital_root(n):
    return w:=sum(int(x) for x in str(n)) if w<10  else digital_root(w)
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense in its current format. Maybe write it in a "less compact" way so people can actually help you on the syntax issue without having to bother with the actual algorithm.

Comment: You assign sum to `w` **if** `w<10`, this is reference before assignment.

Comment: @ ThiefMaster So there isn't any way to solve this using walrus operator in a one-liner like how I attempted do so?

Comment: @dm2 def digital_root(n):
    return w if w:=sum(int(x) for x in str(n))<10  else digital_root(w)

Comment: @Hrishi here's a simplification of your code pointing out two issues:
`w = 1 if w>10 else w`, this breaks down into `if w>10: w=1 else: w=w`; Note: `w` is not assigned before this.

Comment: @dm2 Yes brother, that does work very well when we define w before hand. I was just trying to find a way to use this new Walrus operator. So is it like this operator doesn't work inside return statements?

Comment: The walrus operator does work in return statements (you might need to surround it in `()`), the use of it here doesn't make sense.

Comment: Not to answer the PO directly, but just for fun `math` one-liner:   `def digit_root(n):`  return 1 + (n-1) % 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the walrus operator, you should put it where the `if` condition is:

```
def digital_root(n):
    return w if (w := sum(int(x) for x in str(n))) < 10 else digital_root(w)
```

That's basically a shorter version of this:

```
def digital_root(n):
    if (w := sum(int(x) for x in str(n))) < 10:
        return w 
    else:
        return digital_root(w)
```

Comment: Thank you, it does work. I was just curious to know whether I could shorten the code using the new operator which led me to take the previous approach. Thank you so much, your code worked. It made my day:)

Comment: @Hrishi Yes, you can. Please reload the page - I had updated my answer with a walrus-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're too focused on "short" code to realize you're making silly decisions. There's no point in doing the whole `str`-`int`-`sum` song and dance if `n < 10` -

```py
def digital_root(n):
  if n < 10:
    return n
  else:
    return digital_root(sum(int(x) for x in str(n)))
```

To "shorten" that, you can use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) -

```py
def digital_root(n):
  return n if n < 10 else digital_root(sum(int(x) for x in str(n)))
```

But see how you convert the the number to a string and immediately back using `int`? I understand you're doing this to exploit the iterable property of strings, but you could write a simple iterator for numbers and skip type conversion entirely -

```py
def digits(n):
  yield n % 10
  if n >= 10: yield from digits(n // 10)

def digital_root(n):
  return n if n < 10 else digital_root(sum(digits(n)))
```

The benefit of this is clear. Not only is `digital_root` easier to write, but you also have a useful `digits` function that is useful in any other program that needs this digit-wise functionality.

```py
print(digital_root(16))
print(digital_root(493193))
print(digital_root(942))
```

```py
7
2
6
```

Comment: Sorry, the walrus operator has no use to us here. It's a square peg in a round hole and forcing it is a mistake.

Comment: Your `digits` function returns the digits in reverse order.  Shouldn't matter for this problem, but might in other contexts.

Comment: Who's to say what "reverse" order is? See also [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: I meant reversed compared to what `str` produces, and what most people would expect.  And I just remembered that `reversed()` exists, so it's not a hard thing to fix if it mattered.

Comment: how is string iteration order relevant? what if the number were converted to a tree of factors, a colour, or some other type? how would the iteration order of those representations impact the iteration order of `digits`? if so, why give special consideration to the case of strings?

Comment: Did you miss my disclaimer "shouldn't matter for this problem"?  I just wanted to point out that the order was different than the one produced by the code in the question, and different than a naive but natural expectation.  It's not like I punished you for it.

Comment: i wasn't being rhetorical or snarky... i am aware that the order does not matter but encourage you to resolve _why_ you think the order i used is "reversed" or that anything needs to be "fixed". using walrus operator is a misstep. converting the number to a string is a misstep. these things have no bearing on the "order" or correctness of this answer ‍♀️ See also [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: That's the thing, I didn't ask you to fix anything.  I was just leaving a signpost for someone who came across your excellent code and was tempted to use it in a different context.

Comment: @Mulan Thank you brother for your advise. But I do know that it's not so cool to enforce the Walrus here. Yes, I clearly do understand your viewpoint & stand by it. My intention of using Walrus is simply for the sake of learning how to use it in one-liners, nothing else.